# Will the Intent "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" be broadcast if device is switched off due to 0 battery level?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application which listens to this broadcast so as to save some data when device is about to shut down. It works fine when I manually shut down the device. I am curious to know what would be the behavior if device shuts down because all battery was drained and battery level becomes 0? Would the event be broadcast and system would do a proper shutdown OR system would not be able to shutdown properly?

Comment: y dont u try with a phone and let us know!!

Answer (score 0):

Going by what the API says, I dont see why **ACTION_SHUTDOWN** would not be broadcasted in case of a battery run-out.

> Broadcast Action: Device is shutting down. This is broadcast when the
>   device is being shut down (completely turned off, not sleeping). Once
>   the broadcast is complete, the final shutdown will proceed and all
>   unsaved data lost. Apps will not normally need to handle this, since
>   the foreground activity will be paused as well.

In case it doesnt, you could try to find a suitable work around with **ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED** and **ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED**.

Good Luck

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this happening when you drop the phone and the battery flies out of it though ;-)